# ActiveRecord Selecting First Messages in Bi-Directed Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm looking to select the most recent messages sent in a thread between two users, where the only object is the Message object.

I'm doing it here successfully but I feel like it could be way more efficient, as right now I have to get the most recent that Person A has sent to Person B and then the most recent that Person B has sent to Person A, and then use ruby code to just get the most recent of these two.

```
Message
  .select('DISTINCT ON(person_id, recipient_id) *')
  .where('person_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?', cid, cid)
  .order('person_id, recipient_id, created_at DESC')
  .group_by{|x| x.person_id != cid ? x.person_id : x.recipient_id }
  .map{|k,v| v.sort_by(&:created_at).last}
```

Comment: What's `cid`? How do the relationships in your models look like?

Comment: cid is in this case the id of current user

Each message has a person_id and a recipient_id, both pointing to the person table

Comment: So you're using `cid` to get a message where the person who sent it, and the recipient are the same person? (`'person_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?', cid, cid`)

Comment: That's an OR. So basically I want the current person to be either the sender or the recipient.

Comment: So I'm selecting Distinct on person_id and recipient_id, so it'll get all messages A sent to B, B sent to A, A sent to C, C sent to A, etc..., but only where person A (cid) is either the sender or recipient, so it won't get messages B sent to C or C sent to B.

And then it's ordering them by person_id, recipient_id, created_at, to allow for the grouping while ordering them by newest first. And then it groups them all by the id of the person that is not cid (the group_by). And finally does the map to get whichever is the newest of the messages, A to B, or B to A

Comment: So it totally works, but as I'm sure you can see it, it ain't pretty :p